# Track dns changes in real-time with python script

Tags: python-2.7, dns, lookup

I am trying to write a Python script that allows me to track DNS Nameserver changes in real-time or nearly real-time.

What I want to do is to do a DNS lookup with Python and check if there has been a change since I made the last check.

Now that seems like a pretty simple and straightforward thing to do but the problem that I encountered is that the data needs to be as fresh as possible.

Generally nameserver updates do happen quite fast. I have checked this in my browser and usually can see a new record being live within minutes.

The problem is that caching can delay things quite a bit. Repeated DNS lookups could be delayed up to 72 hours. I could flush the DNS cache on my computer every time before I make a check but I feel that would be impractical.

Also this would not solve the problem of DNS caching at the ISP level.

The idea that I had was to use a proxy server to do the lookups and continually rotate servers from a list of proxies to make sure that the data I get is up to date.

This seems also a bit impractical for something that should in theory be fairly straightforward.

Any other suggestions?

I don't need to check for changes every minute but I would like to check every 30 minutes or so if possible.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My main concern is to get fresh data and circumvent cached results. To give a practical example of what I am trying to do: I want to track nameserver changes of any domain e.g domainxy.com in real-time or nearly real-time(without having to query the WHOIS server). I have tried changing the nameservers of my domain and see them updated in the WHOIS within seconds, while dnspython does not show any changes even after minutes. I am not sur e what I would need to do to get non-cached data.

Comment: A sample python code: import dns.resolver

answers = dns.resolver.query('domain.com', 'NS')
for e in answers:
    print e

Answer (score 0):

OK, there are a few problems here. The first is that the concept "the name servers for a domain" is not quite as well defined as one might wish. For a given domain, information on its set of name servers exists in all its own authoritative servers and all its parent domain's authoritative servers. In a perfect world, they all have exactly the same information. In this world, they often do not. So you have to decide which information you really want, and that depends on what you want the information for (which you're not telling us here).

If you just want to monitor a fixed domain, you can stop here. Figure out which server's information you're interested in, and send it a query ever 30 seconds. Problem solved.

If you want to monitor arbitrary domains, you will find that figuring out which domain is the parent is not as easy as one first thinks. Just chopping off labels doesn't work very well, given that there are delegations that span several steps (extremely common in reverse lookup zones). [Zonemaster](https://github.com/dotse/zonemaster-engine/) has code for finding parents (translation from Perl to Python is left as an exercise for the reader). But once you know the parent domain, you're back to deciding if you want the NS info from there or from the zone's own authoritative servers.

Oh, and there's the "What counts as a separate name server?" problem. If the name `ns1.example.org` points at two IP addresses, one IPv4 and one IPv6, that is *probably* only one actual server. But you can't know for sure.